# How to prevent remote desktop from being idle?

Tags: shell, vbscript, scripting

I am using remote desktop connection to log in Windows Server. The remote desktop auto locks after few minutes if idle and all the process on remote desktop stops. Is there any way to prevent the remote desktop from being idle ?

I've written a shell script which automatically press numlock key every 6 seconds.

```
Dim objResult

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
i = 0

Do While i = 0
  objResult = objShell.sendkeys("{NUMLOCK}{NUMLOCK}")
  Wscript.Sleep (6000)
Loop
```

**But the problem is this code is not working** and runs for infinite time. Can we limit it for 1-2 hours ? Is there any other way ?

Comment: Can we write a script to automatically move the mouse after every few minutes ?

Answer (score 2):

To Limit it to run for 1 hour increment "i" in your loop and run it for only 600 times. (1h = 3600s / 6s --> 600 times)

```
Do While i < 600
  objResult = objShell.sendkeys("{NUMLOCK}{NUMLOCK}")
  Wscript.Sleep (6000)
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

But why not just configure your server to not auto-lock?

Comment: Hi MatSnow, Thanks for the reply. Actually the system admin has disabled launching of display settings control panel. So I am not able to modify the changes.

Answer (score -2):

Script to kill (CMD file)

```
tasklist /FO TABLE /NH | findstr /I "PID script.exe" > c:\temp\kill_vbs.txt

for /F "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims= " %%i in (c:\temp\kill_vbs.txt) do taskkill /F /PID %%i
```

Answer (score -2):

```
(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Monitoring"

[System.Console]::BufferWidth  = [System.Console]::WindowWidth  = 30
[System.Console]::BufferHeight = [System.Console]::WindowHeight = 20

$duration = read-host

$shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

$start_time = Get-Date -UFormat %s <# Get the date in MS #>
$current_time = $start_time
$elapsed_time = 0

Write-Host "The job is still running!"

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$count = 0

while($elapsed_time/60 -lt $duration) {

$shell.sendkeys("{NUMLOCK}{NUMLOCK}") <# Fake some input! #>

if ($count -eq 20) {

$count = 0
Clear-Host

}

if ($count -eq 0) {

$current_time = Get-Date -UFormat %s
$elapsed_time += 60

Write-Host "Added " ($elapsed_time / 60) " !"

} 
else { Write-Host "Loading ..." $count "/20" }

$count ++

Start-Sleep -Seconds 3

}
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.